# специфицировать/перегрузить метод схожими типами в зависимости от значения шаблона

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

столкнулся с проблемой, связанной со спецификацией шаблонов:
У меня, в шаблонном классе есть метод `add`, который должен принимать в зависимости от значения шаблона либо копию объекта, либо ссылку на объект.
через `std::enable_if` не работает, компилятор говорит, что существует несколько экземпляров перегруженного метода `add` соответствующего параметрам.

есть ли способ это реализовать не использую полную специализацию класса? какой?
Если поможет, компилятор: Visual C++, стандарт языка: c++17

```
enum ArrayType { object, simple, pointer };

template<class T, ArrayType TType = object>
class Array
{
    template <class Ret = void>
    using visO = std::enable_if_t<TType == object, Ret>;
    template <class Ret = void>
    using visS = std::enable_if_t<TType == simple, Ret>;
    template <class Ret = void>
    using visP = std::enable_if_t<TType == pointer, Ret>;
    template <class Ret = void>
    using visSP = std::enable_if_t<TType == simple || TType == pointer, Ret>;

public:

    // ...

    template<class = visO<>>
    visO<> add(T const& value);
    template<class = visSP<>>
    visSP<> add(T value);

    // ...
};
```

Использование, компилятор выдаёт ошибку

```
Array<unsigned, simple> arr;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i)
     arr.add(i);
```

Может я просто не правильно понял, как использовать `std::enable_if`?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите - по вашему коду. Впрочем, и по описанию. Вы не это хотите: `template<class T, ArrayType TType = object>
class Array
{
public:
    using add_type =
        typename std::conditional<TType == object, const T&,
        typename std::conditional<TType == simple, T, void>::type>::type;

    void add(add_type x){};
};` ?

Comment: "...в зависимости от значения шаблона...". Что вы имеете в виду под "значением шаблона"?

Comment: AnT, в объявлении `Array<unsigned, simple>` `unsigned` и `simple` я называю значением шаблона

Comment: Я так понимаю, содержимое методов почти одинаковое? Может поставить `std::conditional` в параметр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то в таком духе:

```
enum ArrayType { object, simple, pointer };

template<class T, ArrayType TType = object>
class Array
{
public:
    using add_type =
        typename std::conditional<TType == object, const T&,
        typename std::conditional<TType == simple, T, void>::type>::type;

    void add(add_type x){};
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Array<unsigned, simple> arr;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1'000'000; ++i)
        arr.add(i);
}
```